# My VBA code takes long time to generate a value

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

I have a code that search the value of textbox3 in my data sheet , my code work well but it takes time to generate the answer.. Any better ideas? This is my code:

```
Sub CODE23()
    Dim i As Long, arr

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DATA")
        arr = .Range(.Range("B2"), .Cells(Rows.Count, 43) _ 
        End(xlUp).Offset(0,1)).Value
    End With

    For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
        If arr(i,1)=UserForm1.TextBox3.Text Or  arr(i,1) = _
            Val(UserForm1.TextBox3.Text) Then
            UserForm1.ComboBox6.Value = "FROM " &  _ 
arr(i,43) & " TO "
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Column B2 has the i.d numbers.. And column 43 has the address data..If the user inputs an i.d number in textbox3 the combobox6 will generate a value with the address of the i.d being input.

Comment: There is something wrong with the code you have posted, it will not compile. Can you check and correct?

Comment: what is your intention at this part:  "With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DATA")
        arr = .Range(.Range("B2"), .Cells(Rows.Count, 43) 
        End(xlUp).Offset(0,1)).Value"
    End With

Comment: I have updated my code...@ FunThomas

Comment: @Denyo  sheets("DATA") is where all of my data being stored with a unique i.d number,names,address,age, etc., it is the part where im giving the arr variable a range from B2 untill column 43 , it counts all the data in the sheet

Comment: without knowing your sheet structure i assmue last row with data in column 43 is >= last row with data in columns 2-42

Comment: @Denyo  yes it is....

Comment: is it possible to provide a screenshot of the sheet "Data"?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your array set-up isn't going awry somewhere, (check the value of the UBOUND to be sure) the only way I can see to speed this up would be to stop checking the `Userform1.Textbox3` value every time in your loop. You could do something like this:

```
valCompare = Val(UserForm1.TextBox3.Text)
txtCompare = UserForm1.TextBox3.Text

For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
    If arr(i, 1) = txtCompare Or arr(i, 1) = valCompare Then
        UserForm1.ComboBox6.Value = "FROM " & arr(i, 43) & "TO "
        'Exit For
    End If
Next
```

Also, if you're looking for the ***first*** instance of a match, you would probably want to add in the `Exit For` - but I'm not sure if that's what you're looking for.

Alternatively, you could possibly replace the entire thing with a `Range.Find`

Comment: Thanks for the help.. I tried your code but still my combobox6.value generates too long..any other ideas?

Comment: Have you checked the value of `UBound(arr, 1)` ? And did you un-comment the `Exit For` ?

Comment: Yes, i did both.. The value of UBound(arr,1) is correct..and i tried to uncomment the exit for and run the program and do some testing and still its desame, it take more than 2 secs to generate a value of combobox6

Answer (score 0):

according to CLR answer you can try following:

```
Sub CODE23()

    Dim arr As Range
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim valCompare as String
    Dim txtCompare as String  

    valCompare = Val(UserForm1.TextBox3.Text)
    txtCompare = UserForm1.TextBox3.Text

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DATA")
        Set arr = .Range("B2:" & .Cells(Rows.Count, 43).End(xlUp).Address)
    End With
    ' arr.Select ' uncomment this to check whether the correct range is taken
    For Each rng In arr
        If not isEmpty(rng) Then
            If rng.Value = txtCompare  Or rng.Value = valCompare  Then
                UserForm1.ComboBox6.Value = "FROM " & rng.Value & " TO "
                Exit For ' CAUTION - exits the for each loop after 1st hit
            End If
        End If
    Next rng

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, i've tried your code but it doesnt work properly.. Combobox6.value returns me the value of textbox3 and it takes much more time in generating the result... I also correct the error on userform1.combobox6.value = "FROM " & rag.value & " TO ".......... instead of rag.value i make it rng.value..

Comment: i have add isEmpty to speed up a bit...so empty cells will not be compared. an have stolen some parts of CLRs code

Comment: without more detailed information i can not do more. "Still didnt worked properly as i expected" does explain not much :) ...what is properly for you? what do you expect?

Comment: is it a bit faster, is it slower? does is it provide false/correct values into combobox6